# What happened to my macros after update to Word for Mac 14.5.7?

Tags: mac, ms-office

AutoUpdate loaded the Office Service Pack 14.5.7. When I open MS Word, my macros are no longer there. I tried restoring my Normal.dotm file from

~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/User Templates/

Just realized that custom AutoCorrect entries still exist. I had assumed that they would be missing too.

Still no macros are showing up. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns up that the Office update changed my preferences in MS Word. Previously templates had been stored in

```
~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/User Templates/
```

When AutoUpdate ran, the location changed to

```
~"UserName"/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/User Templates/
```